# Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin

Tags: maven-plugin

Add the following dependencies to the pom file to display error messages：Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:.
The added dependencies are shown in the following figure：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4pV9.png)
Some attempts have been made, but they cannot solve the problem.

Attempted to delete the lastupdated file from Maven warehouse.